# C# go to new page in pdf file without re-opening new instance of the same file

Tags: c#, pdf

I use this code to open pdf file at specific page :

```
  void ShowPDF(SomeObject _obj)
    {
        //
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("D:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat 9.0\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe", "/A page=" + _obg.PageNo + " /n " + _obj.FilePath);
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

        try
        {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);          

        }


        catch
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Page Not Found", "SmartPlant", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }

    }
```

and it works fine. But when i send new page in the same already open document, it opens new instance of the same document at the new page number. What i want is to got to the new page number and not opening new document as long as it the same document

Thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to interop with Office / Acrobat / SumatraPDF viewer and many other apps is via DDE. Though it is not the preferred Adobe method

https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/IAC_DevApp_DDE_Support.html

> If more than one command is sent at once, the commands are executed sequentially, and the results appear to the user as a single action. You can use this feature, for example, to open a document to a certain page and zoom level.
> https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/IAC_API_DDE_Messages.html

There are many command line ways of shelling that start DDE process so there used to be

CMD>DDEblah.exe this and that.

The only one you need is `PDFopen.exe` (which is often copied as PDFclose.exe, both are stubs to PDFDDE.exe for both Pro and Reader) or roll your own DDE driver (source should be in w32tex-src.tar.xz).

There are many versions usually part of oriental W32Tex where it is essential for driving PDF readers.

Mine is from TexLive 2022

```
pdfopen -v
pdfopen of 0.6.
```

there should be a binary in say https://mirror.apps.cam.ac.uk/pub/tex-archive/systems/win32/w32tex/pdftex-w32.tar.xz but since DDE is fickle bitwise, then for 64bit you may need a different one?

Here I open a file at page 3 then tell it to goto page 6 instantly.
[image]

[image]

Note that just the same as the command line switch that "PDFclose --all" will usually just close the PDF(s) and NOT close Acrobat which is a historic TSR trait. However Acrobat should possibly be closable via DDE.

> AppExit
> Exits the Acrobat application.
> AppExit is also supported in Acrobat Reader.
> Syntax
> [AppExit()]
> Returns
> true if the Acrobat application exits successfully, false otherwise.

Also the environment of the pdfopen.exe must NOT be a fresh one i.e. not a fresh process start since the following directions must come from the initiating environment, however it can be a child of the parent environment.

[image]

Comment: As you commented, the preferred way to interact with adobe is using COM, but for OP's case where he is interacting from the command line it might make more sense. Moreover, your solution seems to work also for Adobe Reader, while mine doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with an already running process Acrobat.exe with the command `Process.Start` since as the name indicates, this command is used to start a *new* process.

I think your best bet is to look through the [Adobe SDK documentation](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/index.html) and see if there's any API that let's you interact with the desktop application. In particular, the section [Developing for Interapplication Communication](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/library/interapp/index.html) sounds promising for what you are trying to achieve:

> With IAC, an external application can control Acrobat or Acrobat
> Reader. For example, you can write an application that launches
> Acrobat, opens a specific file, and sets the page location and zoom
> factor.

If you download the Acrobat DC SDK, they even have an example application (BasicIacCS.sln) to open an instance of Adobe and operate with it from a .NET application. You should be able to set the current page using the object `avDoc`:

```
            //IAC objects
        CAcroPDDoc pdDoc;
        CAcroAVDoc avDoc;

        //constant, hard coding for a pdf to open, it can be changed when needed.
        String szPdfPathConst = Application.StartupPath + "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\TestFiles\\TwoColumnTaggedDoc.pdf";

        //variables
        string szStr;
        string szName;
        int iNum = 0;

        //Initialize Acrobat by creating App object
        mApp = new AcroAppClass();

        //Show Acrobat
        mApp.Show();

        //set AVDoc object
        avDoc = new AcroAVDocClass();

        //open the PDF
        if (avDoc.Open (szPdfPathConst, ""))
        {
            //set the pdDoc object and get some data
            pdDoc  = (CAcroPDDoc)avDoc.GetPDDoc ();
            iNum = pdDoc.GetNumPages ();
            szName = pdDoc.GetFileName();

            //compose a message
            szStr = szName + " has been loaded in Acrobat by the IAC application.\n\n";

            if(iNum >1)
                szStr += "The PDF document has " + iNum + " pages.\n";
            else
                szStr += "The PDF document has " + iNum + " page.\n";

            label2.Text = szStr;
        } 
        else 
        {
            label2.Text = "Cannot open " + szPdfPathConst + "\n";
        }
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get this sample application to run due to the following error:

[image]

> **System.InvalidCastException**: 'Error al crear una instancia del componente COM con CLSID {85DE1C45-2C66-101B-B02E-04021C009402} desde IClassFactory debido al siguiente error: 80004002 Interfaz no compatible (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

Comment: What about doing the same functionality using foxit

Comment: The example I posted here is not working because I was using Adobe Reader. The approach works for Adobe Pro (I downloaded the 7 trial day and tried with it). Once you open the example, you can use the method avDoc.MoveTo to move the viewer to a different page.